# Lost build.js. How can I restore it and continue developing it?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I think I lost my build.js. I renamed the assets folder to dist. How do I recover it and continue working with a hot reboot?

[image]

Comment: I found the problem. webpack.config.js . you must always specify the dist directory

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider turning your comment into an answer and mark it as _accepted_, so that people know your issue is solved.